# Please help again with review queues, even if they are short!

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, review

Again posts can linger for too long (days) in the review queues without resolution. Now not because the queues are long, they are short so people forgot to visit them.  See my former question [long review queues](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5386/what-to-do-about-long-review-queues).

For instance, this (to me) obvious duplicate have only two votes to close after 5 days!:  [Distribution for Sum of Square Normal Variables with Arbitrary Variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205043/distribution-for-sum-of-square-normal-variables-with-arbitrary-variance)

Comment: Possible hesitance on that one because the earlier question is either more general (if the X's are independent) or less general (if they're not MVN). Question probably should have been clarified instead but I have closed as duplicate as you suggest and OP can still clarify and flag if that's not sufficient. [Edit: I see OP indicates independence in comments but has not said so in the Q; so the original is more general, in which case there may be closer duplicates]